# Is there a "complete" set of functions/operators for FRP?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

Functional Reactive Programming is an approach to specify side-effecting programs in a pure functional way.

Recently I've been using rxscala, which is the Java/Scala port port of ReactiveX. It is based around the concept of `Observable`s that can be regarded as streams of values of a certain type.

**For this question I want to exclude FRP approaches that handle time-continuous changes (signals).**

### Building new Observables from old ones

These Observables can be combined using a wealth of different functions to create new observables. These are similar to the functions that can be applied to collections. And those are already quite well understood, as we know `Foldable`, `Traversable`, `Applicative`, `Monads` and the like.

Indeed observables are foldable, traversable monads, like ordinary collections. But these traits can be implemented in multiple ways for observables, as an observable holds much more information (the timing information for each element) than an ordinary collection. And the result also has to be fitted with timing information.

### Two Monad implementations

For example the monadic `join` (`flatMap` in Scala) can be implemented in at least two different, plausible ways:

- By `switch`ing between the nested observables, which results in truncating the currently active observable, once the next one begins emission, or

  [RxJava Switch Visualization http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/images/switch.c.png](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/images/switch.c.png)
- by `merge`ing the nested observables without dropping or delaying any events.

  [RxJava Merge Visualization http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/images/mergeDelayError.C.png](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/images/mergeDelayError.C.png)
- ... and much much more (see the comments)

### Limitations

I'm very pleased with the provided repertoire of combinator functions, but I keep running into situations where I'm not able to achieve what I want, and I have to fall back to some kind of concurrent programming.

### Missing combinators or brains?

Now I'm wondering whether I'm just too stupid to construct the desired behavior using existing combinators. Or is it the case that the combinator functions available in rxscala are not sufficient to create every imaginable behavior?

## Question

I'm asking for a proof that some basic set of combination functions `B` is enough to create "every conceivable observable" from some input observables.

Possibly the hardest part might be the definition of "every conceivable observable".
Maybe the Haskell community has produced something like this?

Comment: This is more theory than a practical problem. Perhaps [CSSE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) is better suited?

Comment: I don't think the question makes much sense as it's written. While reactive libraries try to be as general as possible, they usually are designed with particular kinds of domains in mind. For example, you have the netwire library for haskell that assumes most things are continuous values with the occasional need for events, whereas some other library might place a lot more emphasis on events and supply an abstraction on top of those allowing you to treat values as if they were continuous. It might simply be your domain doesn't fit the model this library is providing very well.

Comment: @Cubic I didn't think about time-continuous frame-works. I'll exclude them from the question, as this might differ much from the discrete case. Otherwise I have to disagree with your assumption that the library did not fit my usecase – it fit perfectly well but was merely lacking some special functions (but maybe it wasn't).

Comment: I don't think that `Observable` can be an instance of `Foldable` -- you can't fold over *all* values that have occurred, because there may be infinitely many!

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus Does this mean you cannot `fold` over an infinite `List`, too?

Comment: If you like thinking in terms of `Foldable`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, etc, you might like [rxscalaz](https://github.com/everpeace/rxscalaz).

Comment: And BTW a third possible implementation of the monadic join would be `concatMap`...

Comment: @SamuelGruetter: Could we see an example/explanation for `concatMap`?

Comment: @ziggystar what did you use to create those graphics?

Comment: besides `concatMap`, there's also `exclusiveMap` (throwaway new inner observables while you are processing the current inner observable...sort of the opposite of `switch`).  `concatMapLatest`, like `exclusiveMap` but keep the last inner observable observed while processing the current inner observable, and once the current one finishes, switch to that last one`.

Comment: @ziggystar That's correct, it's not possible to fold over an infinite list. Otherwise, what would `sum [1..]` be? It is possible to fold over finite lists, of course, but the thing is that `Observable`s are never finite -- at least not until the program ended. The best you can do is `scanl`.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus Well, in rxscala, observables can indeed end. And if you `fold` over such a case, you will receive a result once the observable terminates; it follows that `fold :: (X -> Y -> X) -> X -> O Y -> O X`, note the result type. I admit that's not the ordinary type of `fold`.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2010/01/01/the-essence-of-linq-minlinq.aspx) and [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-MinLINQ-The-Essence-of-LINQ). There, Bart de Smet proposes a minimal set of operations that can build every other operator there is. I guess, for performance reasons, one should probably not try to implement every operator there is by the basic operators but it's an interesting exercise to try for some.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was looking for this article and could not find it

Comment: I've skimmed over the article, and now I'm a bit disappointed. Apparently the author is merely explaining monads and some useful related concepts. He doesn't address the problems mentioned in the OP (e.g. multiple sane definitions of `join`).